# How Do I grab the User Id from database to display the profile for one single user when they are logged in?

Tags: php, database, authentication, mysqli, userid

I have a separate file 'login.php' for logging users into the website, which works perfectly.
I have created another file 'loggedin.php' which will display the Logged In user's info from the database. The problem is that every user in the database has their info displayed because I can't find a way to connect the user's id to display this user's info alone using the "WHERE" statement. The entire code is like this.

```
<?php
reguire 'includes/dbh.inc.php';

$sql = "SELECT * FROM register WHERE registerId=?????";

$query = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
$queryResult = mysqli_num_rows($query);
if($queryResult > 0){
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
        echo "<h4>Hello </h4>".$row['registerName'];
        echo "<a href='profile.php'>Visit Your Profile</a>";
    }
}else{
    exit();
}

 ?>
```

I need help to be able to connect the Loggedin user's id so the page will display only the loggedin user's info.

Comment: Put the ID of the user into the SESSION in the login script if login is successful

Comment: Then in this script get it out again and use it in the query

Comment: Are you referring to something like this?                                                                                ```                                                                                                                                     if(isset($_SESSION['id'])){                                                                                              require 'includes/dbh.inc.php';                                                                                      $sql = "SELECT * FROM register WHERE registerId = ".$_SESSION['id'].";       }

Comment: @KwasiKumi yes, this will return the id of the current user's session. You can use that to find the info relative to the current user. ( where your `????` is. )  Make sure your are [binding your parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/5784924) though, don't want to get any SQL injections.

Comment: ANd you have to have a `start_session()` in all scripts and of course set a value in the other script

Comment: I've got it. Thanks a lot

Comment: I use prepare statement for all my queries. I will surely do it. Thanks